# How to make a grouped bar chart from only measures in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have several measures. For example A,B,C. Each measure has several numerical values(the same amount). I want to make a grouped bar chart, with the min the max and mean of each of these measures. Like this:

```
----------------------------------
   |A.max  |===================
A  |A.min  |===
   |A.mean |==========
----------------------------------
----------------------------------
   |B.max  |==========
B  |B.min  |====
   |B.mean |======
----------------------------------
----------------------------------
   |C.max  |===================
C  |C.min  |========
   |C.mean |===============
----------------------------------
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: What does your data look like (how is it organized)?

Comment: One feature to read about in the online help that may be useful is “Measure Names” and “Measure Values”. That may not be the only important feature needed, depending on how your data is organized, but it is likely part of the solution — and useful to understand regardless

Comment: @Bob I don't know what do you expect but the data look like integer between 5 and 250 for all column

Answer (score 1):

Add group and measure names to the row shelf.

Add Measure Values to the columns shelf.
[image: Solution]

Comment: What's "group" ? How can i make a group ? Why do you have one mesure ? I have 3 mesures

Comment: Read the online help in tableau about “Measure Values”